# How to read Aurdino signals from Android PC emulator

Tags: android, arduino

I am new to Android and Arduino development. I have an app where I want to read to the signals from the Arduino Board: Arduino MEGA ADK r3 and use the information from the board to display on the Andriod Emulator or an Andriod device.

What is the best and simplest way to get started with this project?
Thank you